# Why won't shapely split my line with this point?

Tags: shapely

I have a long Linestring and I'm getting 2 points on the linestring with shapelies closest_points. That seems to work fine however calling `.split()` with the line and one of the closest points as args returns the original object, no split. Why is that?

```
    shapely_track = wkt.loads(act.track.wkt)
    shapely_seg = wkt.loads(seg.track.wkt)
 

    startpoint, endpoint = shapely_seg.boundary
    segment_start, point = nearest_points(shapely_track,startpoint)  
    segment_end, point = nearest_points(shapely_track,endpoint)  

    splitted = split(shapely_track,segment_start)
    #splitted_again = split(splitted[1], segment_end)
    print(len(splitted)) 
    
    >>>1
```

Visually everything is allright, points are on the line since i got them with nearest_point, nu funky buisness going on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a floating point imprecision issue, I added minimal `.buffer()` to the point before applying `.split()`